# How to looping rows and then columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table as shown below (B1:L7)
Where A1 is lookup values , column B is the header , columns C to L are the data
[image: Picture showing the table to be searched of loop]

Here is what I intend to do with the macro:

1. Loop the column B using the lookup values in A1
2. Once match, in example below, B6 shows matching values to A1 , the values of first 10 values (C to L) (i.e:row 6)  are looped to show the values

I have been rig up some macro as followed which it works correctly on step 1

```
Sub Looping_Click()
'Search columns
Dim c As Range
'Search rows
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each r In Range("B:B")
    If r.Value = Range("A1").Value Then
        MsgBox "Found values at " & r.Address
        
        For Each c In r.Columns
            i = 1
            Do While i <= 10
            MsgBox "Values is " & c.Value
            i = i + 1
            Loop
            
        Next c
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

But upon reaching step 2, it somehow repeat showing the B6 values 10 times instead of displaying C A C T C A A T C C

[image: Error Values shows 10 times]

Comment: So instead of showing the value of B6 you want to show the combined values of C6 through L6 with spaces between?

Comment: @Bee_Riii , I did mention this .C A C T C A A T C C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to your task:

```
Sub Looping_Click()
'Search columns
Dim c As Range
'Search rows
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    If r.Value = Range("A1").Value Then
        MsgBox "Found values at " & r.Address
        
        For Each c In Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r.Offset(0, 10))
            MsgBox "Values is " & c.Value
        Next c
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

I mainly changed following things compared to your version:

1. Changed `For Each r In Range("B:B")` to `For Each r In Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))`. Like this the loop will not be carried out over all rows of column `B`.
2. Changed `For Each c In r.Columns` to `For Each c In Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r.Offset(0, 10))`. This was the key to the unexpected result. Before, you were looping ten times over the cell that you had found. Thanks to the `offset` it will loop through the desired range.

Answer (score 2):

you checked column b `For Each r In Range("B:B")` to find interesting  for you value in A1.

macro find this value on range B6 and the you want to show msgbox 10 times because `For Each c In r.Columns` there is only one range in column B:B. (B6)

you need change it to

```
For i = 3 To 13
   MsgBox Cells(r.Row, i)
Next i
```

full working code

```
Sub Looping_Click()
'Search columns
Dim c As Range
'Search rows
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each r In Range("B:B")
    If r.Value = "" Then Exit For
    If r.Value = Range("A1").Value Then
        MsgBox "Found values at " & r.Address
        For i = 3 To 13
            MsgBox Cells(r.Row, i)
        Next i
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

i add exit loop while value on b is nothing