# Excel VBA - Copy Values from Row First and Paste into Column

Tags: excel, vba

This is continuation of my question from here :
[How to looping rows and then columns in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025736/how-to-looping-rows-and-then-columns-in-excel)

I have stumbled another roadblock as I pull all night over this issue:
To recap:

I have a table as shown below (B1:L7) Where A1 is lookup values , row B is the header , row C to L is the data.

Column N is the visual representation of end result going to looked like. It is bolded and highlighted for clarity.

<s>*Note : Highly discouraged solutions of selecting the whole row and transpose paste due to there are conditional formatting at column N for further analysis.*</s>

[image: Excel Table]

Here is what I intend to do with the macro below:

1. Loop the row B using the lookup values in A1 for matching- DONE
2. Once macro found matching values to lookup values, (i.e :B6 shows matching values to A1) , the values of first 10 values (C to L) (i.e:row 6) are looped to show the values - DONE
3. <s>All of 10 values are copied at columns N (starting N1 and reiterates downwards to N10) (i.e:C6 values are copied to N1 , D6 to N2 , etc...)</s>
4. While iterating thru the rows , select the range and paste transpose the values selection in cell N1

```
    Sub Looping_Click()
    'Search columns
    Dim c As Range
    'Search rows
    Dim r As Range
    'Range to copy and paste values
    Dim i As Range
    
    For Each r In Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        If r.Value = Range("A1").Value Then
            MsgBox "Found values at " & r.Address
            
            For Each c In Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r.Offset(0, 10))
                MsgBox "Values is " & c.Value
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                MsgBox "Values is " & c.Value
                r.Selection.Copy
                Next i
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                Range("N1").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    End Sub
```

The problem is when I running macro, there are no values being pasted at column N as well as RunTimeError 438 pops out
I have highlighted the related / suspected troublesome macro parts with ''''
[image: Run Time Error 438]

Comment: You do know you can paste *values* only while transposing, right? That won't overwrite conditional formatting.

Comment: Or you can use `Application.Transpose` to transpose the values.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this approach.

```
Sub Looping_Click()
    ' 167
    
    Dim Fnd         As Range        ' target to find
    Dim Arr         As Variant      ' values in found row
    Dim R           As Long         ' targeted row

    ' find the value of cell A1 in column B (=columns(2))
    Set Fnd = Columns(2).Find(Cells(1, "A").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The requested value wans't found.", _
               vbInformation, "Unsuccessful search"
    Else
        ' define a range from the cell where the match was found,
        ' starting 1 cell to the right and then 10 cells wide, 1 row high
        ' read all found values from that range into an array
        Arr = Fnd.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 10).Value
        
        ' define a range from the cell N1, make it the same size as the array,
        ' then paste the array to the target range transposing the one column into one row.
        Cells(1, "N").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
    End If
End Sub
```

### EDIT:

Referring to your comment, clarity is in the eye of the beholder but one argument would be that the fewer parts a machine has the less complicated it is and therefore the easier it will be to maintain. The above procedure has 3 parts.

1. Find the matching row.
2. Copy the values from that row
3. Paste the copied values to a destination.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for your help but I prefer the code to have clearer style for sake of maintainability in the future. Still stuck on the part of where to copy the data / paste transpose to columns

Comment: Hi Alan, it's impossible to read the same code twice with the same knowledge because one learns from what one reads. My code is extremely simple and therefore exceedingly easy to maintain. I have added more comments, however, to facilitate reading it.